# Examples of clique in categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $I$ be a non empty set and $\mathcal{C}$ a category. Let $(A_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a family  of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\big(f_{ij}:A_{j}\longrightarrow A_{i}\big)_{(i,j)\in I\times I}$. We say that is a $\textbf{clique}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ if the following conditions holds:

1. For any $i,j,r$ in $I$ we have:
   $$ f_{rj}\circ f_{ji} = f_{ri}.$$
2. For any $i\in I$, $f_{ii}=id_{A_{i}}$, that is, the identity morphism of the object $A_i$.

I would like to have examples of this structure, can you suggest one ?

Comment: There are many, I think. For example, the transition functions of a vector bundle over some open cover.

Comment: @B.Pasternark Thank you. I don't know that one I will search on that.

Comment: I was looking for a basic example to write an introductory book on category theory.

Comment: I haven't thought about it too hard, but I believe your definition of a clique can also be formulated as simply a functor into $\mathcal{C}$ from the [indiscrete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indiscrete+category) generated by the set of objects $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$. Actually, it would be better to just say from the indiscrete category generated by $I$ itself.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to prove it and see if I can give an example from there. Thank you!

Comment: One of the simplest examples are the trivial cases one object but it is boring. The next simplest example corresponds to isomorphisms.

Comment: @leibnewtz: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your definition, each $f_{ij}$ is invertible, i.e. an *isomorphism*, since $f_{ij}\circ f_{ji}=1_{A_i}$ and $f_{ji}\circ f_{ij}=1_{A_j}$.

So, a clique is just a collection of isomorphic objects, with a distinguished isomorphism between each of them.

Note that all the remaining $f_{ij}$'s are automatically generated once some $f_{ij}$ isomorphisms are given along a *spanning tree* of the full graph $I\times I$. 
For example, once a bunch of isomorphic objects is given, pick one of them and pick an arbitrary isomorphism from this one to the other ones. This is a spanning tree, a star, and by rule 1. all your other isomorphisms gets evaluated.